# Как добавить поддержку Passkey в код python?

Tags: python, macos, авторизация

можно ли как-то из кода Python вызвать окно получения ключа доступа в macOS? чтобы это выглядело как-то так:
`passkey = get_passkey()`

после чего появлялось такое окно
[image]

и я получал этот ключ в переменную при успешном сканировании Touch ID